# Using URL variables in and include statement PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to use a URL variable to trigger which page is included with "Include" in PHP. This is very easy in Coldfusion with simple line, how can this be done without a bunch of if statements?

```
<a href="index.php?pageid=products" >products</a>
include('/inc'.$_GET['pageid']).'.php');
```

Comment: Talk about insecure. Spend the extra lines of code to make sure your code is safe.

Comment: Unless your php file is called `/incproducts.php`, you probably need `include('inc/'...`

Comment: As an aside, note that `include` is a statement, not a function, so those brackets are unnecessary and misleading (they don't matter as such, but the misunderstanding can lead to some odd bugs sometimes).

Comment: I removed them and it works thank you.

Comment: @IMSoP: Sorry, didn't realize that. Offtopic, but it's the same with `echo`?

Comment: @user2353018: I'd highly recommend an ID to name conversion. Ex `1=>products`, if that's ugly, at least have an array of accepted values such as `$accept=array('products','news','reports');`.

Comment: @DaveChen Yep, `echo` is also a statement, and in that case the brackets can make a direct difference - you can echo multiple strings with `echo $a, $b;`, but `echo($a, $b);` is a syntax error (in the same way `some_function( ($a, $b) )` would be).

Comment: but to echo @JohnConde, I wouldn't ever do this. I've seen tons and tons of sites do this get owned as bad_guys submit pagedid=../../../../../etc/passwd  or pageid=../dbconfig, etc.  until they find something that works..

Answer (score 0):

this may be the shortest code for the question:

to make thing easier create a file named: ***inc.404.php*** to handle errors

```
<?php
    $page = (array_key_exists('page', $_GET) ? $_GET['page'] : '404');//we're sure that inc.404.php is there
    $filename = 'inc.' . $page . '.php';
    if(is_file($filename) === false){
       $filename = 'inc.404.php';
    }
    include $filename;
?>
```

but using php frameworks like [symfony](http://www.symfony.com) make the world a better place